# Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>' in type cast in request flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Hi I am getting this error. As I understand it, it appears when a request is made to the server, I don’t understand why.
By the way, I tried to find the answer here, but unfortunately, either the answers are not clear to me, or they do not suit me.

Here is some information that might be useful to you

- Response from the server in the form -
  [image: response]

Model -

```
factory DetailsModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return DetailsModel(
        cpu: json['CPU'],
        camera:json['camera'],
        id: json['id'],
        price: json['price'],
        rating: json['rating'],
        sd: json['sd'],
        ssd:json['ssd'],
        title: json['title'],
        capacity: json['capacity'],
        color: json['color'],
        images:json['images']
    );
  }
```

Request -

```
class DetailsRemoteDataSorceImpl implements DetailsRemoteDataSorce {
  final http.Clientclient;

  DetailsRemoteDataSorceImpl({required this.client});
  
  @override
  Future<List<DetailsModel>> getAllDetails() async {
    final response = await http.get(
        Uri.parse(ConfigUrl.details),
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    );
    if(response.statusCode == 200) {
       final details = json.decode(response.body);
      return (details as List).map((e) => DetailsModel.fromJson(e)).toList();
    } else {
      throw ServerException();
    }
  }
}
```

And here's how I'm trying to display -

```
Text(details[0].title,)
```

response.body -

```
Result response.body: {CPU: Exynos 990, camera: 108 + 12 mp, capacity: [126, 252], color: [#772D03, #010035], id: 3, images: [https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-mpic/5235334/img_id5575010630545284324.png/orig, https://www.manualspdf.ru/thumbs/products/l/1260237-samsung-galaxy-note-20-ultra.jpg], isFavorites: true, price: 1500, rating: 4.5, sd: 256 GB, ssd: 8 GB, title: Galaxy Note 20 Ultra}
```

Please help, I spent about 3-4 hours on this

Comment: your json response is not List so don't use map instead use this or return this ``` DetailsModel.fromJson(details))

Comment: could you please print response.body?

Comment: @eamirho3ein I have corrected the question, can you please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in your api response, it is returning a single object not list of them, if you expect a list of item maybe you should contact backend developer, but if receive what you want, you should do this:

```
if(response.statusCode == 200) {
       List<DetailsModel> result =[];
       DetailsModel detail = DetailsModel.fromJson(json.decode(response.body))
       result.add(detail);
       return result;
    } else {
      throw ServerException();
    }
```

Comment: `result.addAll(details);`
Error - The argument type 'DetailsModel' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Iterable<DetailsModel>'.

Comment: change var detail to DetailsModel detail @Daniil

Comment: Error has not changed

Comment: I think you are doing some thing wrong.

Comment: Indeed, I was mistaken, this solved my problem, but can you tell me what it was?

Comment: I explain your first issue in my answer, but the last issue you face with was when you try define variable  with var, dart gonna set it as dynamic, and when we try to add a dynamic variable to a list of  DetailsModel, it is going to give us error.

Answer (score 0):

as i see your model accepts some lists so you have to convert your model like this below :

```
class DetailsModel {
  String? cPU;
  String? camera;
  List<String>? capacity;
  List<String>? color;
  String? id;
  List<String>? images;
  bool? isFavorites;
  int? price;
  double? rating;
  String? sd;
  String? ssd;
  String? title;

  DetailsModel(
      {this.cPU,
      this.camera,
      this.capacity,
      this.color,
      this.id,
      this.images,
      this.isFavorites,
      this.price,
      this.rating,
      this.sd,
      this.ssd,
      this.title});

  DetailsModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    cPU = json['CPU'];
    camera = json['camera'];
    capacity = json['capacity'].cast<String>();
    color = json['color'].cast<String>();
    id = json['id'];
    images = json['images'].cast<String>();
    isFavorites = json['isFavorites'];
    price = json['price'];
    rating = json['rating'];
    sd = json['sd'];
    ssd = json['ssd'];
    title = json['title'];
  }}
```

and your request will be somthing like this :)

```
  getAllDetails() async {
    final response = await http.get(
        Uri.parse(ConfigUrl.details),
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    );
    if(response.statusCode == 200) {
       final details = json.decode(response.body);
      return DetailsModel.fromJson(details));
    } else {
      throw ServerException();
    }
  }
```

I hope it will work :)

Comment: `return DetailsModel.fromJson(details);`
Error - A value of type 'DetailsModel' can't be returned from the method 'getAllDetails' because it has a return type of 'Future<List<DetailsModel>>'.

Comment: sorry i edited try now :)

Comment: I don't see the difference, tell me what has changed

Comment: getAllDetails Function before it returns Future<List<DetailsModel>> but now return Future<DetailsModel>

Comment: In the line `Future<DetailsModel> getAllDetails() async {`
Error - DetailsRemoteDataSorceImpl.getAllDetails' ('Future<DetailsModel> Function()') isn't a valid override of 'DetailsRemoteDataSorce.getAllDetails' ('Future<List<DetailsModel>> Function()'). (Documentation)
The member being overridden (details_remote_data_sources.dart:11).

Comment: remove the override